# Convert columns into rows for each ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, transformation

I have a table that looks as follows

```
ID  | value1 | value2 | value3
1   | 5      | 6      | 7
2   | 10     | 11     | 12
3   | 20     | 21     | 22
```

I need to create one row for each of the 3 value columns per `ID`. The final table should look like this (the column headers dont make sense anymore, but you can ignore this):

```
ID  | value1 | value2
1   | value1 | 5     
1   | value2 | 6     
1   | value3 | 7     
2   | value1 | 10     
2   | value2 | 11    
2   | value3 | 12    
3   | value1 | 20     
3   | value2 | 21    
3   | value3 | 22
```

What would be the best way to approach this in TSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *unpivot* the data you can use `CROSS APPLY` for that

```
Select Id,cs.name,cs.values_list from yourtable 
cross apply (values ('value1',value1),
                    ('value2',value2),
                    ('value3',value3)) Cs (name,values_list)
```

Comment: That was fast.  Was in your clipboard?  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Nope ;) Just got used to it ;)

Comment: thanks for the quick help. just have some (hopefully) minor syntactic issues: where does `name` and `values` in the `SELECT` come from? `yourtable` is the name of the initital table right? because it does not contain any columns named `name` and `values`. hence, I get a syntax error.

Comment: @beta `cross apply (amounts..` should be  `cross apply (values...` `values` is tabled valued constructor (keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot operator

```
select  id,value1,value2
from    t unpivot (value2 for value1 in (value1,value2,value3)) u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpivot.

Select ID,vals,val from 
(Select * from stack) stc
UNPIVOT
(val for vals in (value1,value2,value3)
) as vals1