# Rotate Excel table on ID field make columns repeat as rows for each ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transformation, vba

I am attempting to do what is described in [This Stack Exchange page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286008/convert-columns-into-rows-for-each-id) but instead of doing it in SQL I want to do it in Excel. I have date in a Horizontal table that I want to rotate along the ID column and take the column names as Attribute Name rows with their IDxAttribName reference showing in the Attribute Value field of the final product. The images below show an example of what I have now and what I want. I just need a point in the right direction with a formula or example vba. Any help is appreciated.

Before:
[image: What it looks like now]

After:
[image: What I would like it to look like]

Answer (score 0):

Say the original is in cols **A**, **B**, and **C**.

In **F2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,1+ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0))
```

and copy down.  In **G2** enter:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROWS($1:1)),"inch","milli")
```

and copy down. In **H2** enter:

```
=OFFSET($C$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,2))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**What is going on:**

Column **F** just duplicates column **A**, but doubles the entries *(Snafu is doubled)*.
Column **G** is a flip-flop
Column **H** maps columns **B&C** into a single column.

Using relatively simple formulas you can:

1. map a table into a single row or a single column
2. map a single row or column into a table
3. reorganize a table

Answer (score 0):

This is for Excel 2016, so if you have a different version, you may need to adapt slightly (it seems like the menu items changes, but this functionality is probably in most recent versions).
1. Select the data you want to transform.
2. Go to the **Data** tab, click **From table**.
3. The Query Editor opens.
4. Select the 'Polarity', 'Diameter Inches', and 'Diameter Millimeters' columns.
5. Click on the **Transform** tab, click on **Unpivot Columns**.
6. Go back to the **Home** tab, click **Close & Load**.
It puts the results in a new tab.